# Why does the cost function contain a 2 at the denominator?

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning, math

A cost function used in machine is often the following

$$C = \frac{1}{2} \| y - \hat{y} \| ^2$$

Why is there $\frac{1}{2}$ in front of the squared distance?

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/q/884887/168764 for more elaborate and precise answers.

Answer (score 4):

To simplify the derivative, probably. Otherwise there will be constant 2 in it.

Comment: This is the correct answer. The constant factor does not affect the optimizer of the loss, so the only reason is convenience.

Comment: I think it would also useful if you explain in which way it exactly simplifies the derivative (i.e. show a step by step example).

Comment: @Harsh Yes, but I think these details should be elaborated a little more (i.e. explained more in detail), given that they might not obvious to everyone, so this question needs to be improved, IMHO.